# Multiplayer browser game: linear interpolation causing jittering and jumping

Tags: javascript, interpolation, multiplayer, motion, linear-interpolation

I'm developing a browser multiplayer game, in which each client interpolates (linear) the frames of entities sent by the server. It doesn't look too bad at a high framerate (> 30fps), but starts to jitter at lower framerates (< 30fps) and freezes and jumps and very low framerates (< 10fps). I want to reduce the framerate, and I know it's possible (see [Brutal.io](http://brutal.io) which sends updates at 10fps).

This is the basic algorithm which I'm using:

- The server sends updates at a framerate (say, 10fps)
- The client renders the game at a framerate (say, 60fps)
- The client doesn't update the entities on screen to match the server's data straight up: this would look jittery
- Instead, it uses a linear interpolation function to smooth out the frames between server updates
- With the example of 10:60fps, the client would render 6 frames in between to create a smooth animation
- It does this by measuring the delta (difference) between server updates, and also with client render frames
- It then gets a multiplier by diving client delta by server delta
- Then, it calls the linear interpolation function, using the screen position, server position, and multiplier, to generate a new screen position

This snippet doesn't contain specific code, but should be good enough to demonstrate the basic overview (see comments in code for info):

```
var serverDelta = 1; // Setting up a variable to store the time between server updates

// Called when the server sends an update (aiming for 10fps)
function onServerUpdate(message) {
    serverDelta = Date.now() - lastServerFrame;
}

// Called when the client renders (could be as high as 60fps)
var onClientRender() {
    var clientDelta = Date.now() - lastUpdateFrame;

    // Describes the multiplier used for the linear interpolation function
    var lerpMult = clientDelta / serverDelta;
    if (lerpMult > 1) { // Making sure that the screen position doesn't go beyond the server position
        lerpMult = 1;
    }
    lastUpdateFrame = Date.now();

    ...

    // For each entity
    // ($x,$y) is position sent by server, (x,y) is current position on screen
    entity.x = linearInterpolate(entity.x, entity.$x, lerpMult / 2);
    entity.y = linearInterpolate(entity.y, entity.$y, lerpMult / 2);
}

function linearInterpolate(a, b, f) {
    return (a * (1 - f)) + (b * f);
};
```

As stated above, this creates jitter and jumping in the motion. Is there something I'm doing wrong? How would I make this motion smooth?

Comment: I'm trying to understand - how do you know what the final server frame is (in the interpolation) before it happens? In other words, how to interpolate between one value and another value you don't know, without causing lag?

Comment: Hmm ok, so are you saying that the way I'm doing it has it interpolating using a delta from the frame before, with the current values? Would the solution be to store a "last server delta" and use that?

Comment: @clabe45 Sorry, forgot to mention you. See above ^^^.

Comment: @clabe45 I just tried that: it makes it smoother, but the entities still jump every few seconds.

Comment: But wouldn't doing the "last server delta" cause significant lag?

Comment: @clabe45, maybe it would. Any ideas on what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interpolation must be between two server states.  You can keep a history of the last X server states received on the client.  Each server state represents a specific frame.

For example, let's say your client kept the following server states and their frames:

```
state[0] = {frame: 0, ... };
state[1] = {frame: 10, ... };
state[2] = {frame: 20, ... };
```

If the client is now rendering frame 15, then it must interpolate the positions half-way between `state[1]` and `state[2]`.  The formula is

```
// prev=1, next=2 
let interpolatePercent = (clientFrame - serverState[prev].frame) / serverUpdateRate;
entity.x = interpolatePercent * (serverState[next].entity.x - serverState[prev].entity.x) + serverState[prev].entity.x;
```

In your code, `lerpMult` may well be larger than 1, in which case you are now doing extrapolation instead of interpolation which is much harder.

Also you may also want to take a look at the open source library which implements interpolation (and extrapolation) for browser multiplayer games: https://github.com/lance-gg/lance